# c++ string loops checking the same words

Tags: c++, string, loops

I have to get let's say 10 words from the user.The program will warn the user if the same word is entered again.What could be the general logic of the program ? I managed to take 10 words from the user with a loop but cant check if the entered words are all different or not ?

Comment: Would you share your code so far?

Comment: use a `std::set`, and `std::set::insert` will tell you if the word alreay existed

Comment: Store the words in a std::set and before inserting a word try to find the word in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `std::set`, which by definition may not have any duplicates, all elements must be unique. You could do something like

```
std::set<std::string> uniqueWords;
while (uniqueWords.size() < 10)
{
    std::string user;
    std::cin >> user;
    uniqueWords.insert(user);
}
```

If the user inputs a duplicate word, [`set::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) will not add the duplicate, so the length of the `set` will not increase. The `while` loop will only terminate once the length of the set grows to 10 elements. Then you can continue on.

Answer (score 1):

Save the words and check if you already have them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> words;

    for (std::string word; std::cin >> word; )
    {
        if (!words.insert(std::move(word)).second)
        {
            std::cout << "Word already encountered!\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "We got " << words.size() << " distinct words.\n";

    // use "words"
}
```

(You can add a counter or check `words.size()` if you want at most a certain number of words.)